# What does "с др кароч" mean?

Tags: сленг

I realize that **кароч** is related to the answers given to [What does “короче” mean?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/5653/what-does-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5-mean), but what about **с др кароч**? I've seen it in the title of Youtube videos where people talk for a short time, and on "image macros".

Comment: с др means "с днем рожденья" (Happy Birthday)

Comment: It means that Dr. Imre Kertesz (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imre_Kert%C3%A9sz, pronounced in Russian as Кароч) was involved in the filming. Just kidding.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`ДР` means `день рождения` (`birthday`)
`с др` (`c днём рождения`) - `happy birthday`

Comment: Thank you. Does "кароч" just make it sound "cooler" for teens?

Comment: @screener I am not sure about "cooler", but it apparently makes the phrase very informal.

Comment: "кароч" = "короче", this word is used just for fun so it can be translated as "well, happy birthday"

Comment: "кароч" = "короче", this word is used to point you want to shorteh conversation and now will speak only on topic so it can be translated as "well, happy birthday". About "короче" see here http://absurdopedia.net/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5

Comment: Спасибо, Dmitry¹ и Dmitry². :)

Comment: *Кароч* tries to mimic yob phonetics. Think *Nah* as opposed to *No*. I'd loosely translate is as: *'kay, I mean -- have a good one, man*. 'Make it sound "cooler" for teens' is certainly one way of putting it.

Answer (score 5):

It's like "HB though", where HB stands for Happy Birthday

Answer (score 2):

i suppose that *с др кароч* beginning from social web вконтакте. you have smb in friend-list there, so you see notice that today is др of this person. but you don't know him\her good enough to know what smb would like to see from you. or  you just wouldn't like to write and think a long wishes to him. so tengeers wrote *с др кароч*. now it's funny mem.

Answer (score 2):

"Короче говоря, с днём рождения."

др - распространённое сокращение от день рождения.
кароч - короче говоря.  (В устной речи - распространённое слово-паразит.)

Не следует пользоваться сокращением "кароч", потому что это разговорное слово низкоинтеллектуальных подростков. Сокращение "др" не особенно вежливо, им не следует пользоваться для поздравления собеседника.